# What are the default MIME types for IIS 7?

Tags: iis, mime

Is there a list of the default MIME types for IIS 7 somewhere?

The one I am most concerned with right now is that for `.zip` files.

I know `application/zip` will work, but IIS 7 has something else by default... I just can't remember what it is.

On that same note, is there a way to reset all the MIME types to their default values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The IIS7 default is `application/x-zip-compressed`

I don't know of a way to remove all custom MIME types.

Comment: Best I could find is [this list](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb742440.aspx) from 1999 showing the default mime mapping in IIS 4.0 and 5.0 :(

Answer (score 8):

You can get an authoritative list for your machine by looking at applicationHost.config at %windir%\system32\inetsrv\config\applicationHost.config.

Search for mimeMap and it will jump to the first one.  The default .zip mime type is 'application/x-zip-compressed'.

You can edit with IIS Manager at the server level (MIME Types icon) or you can edit applicationHost.config in notepad if you want.  Just make sure that you keep good XML formatting and that you don't overwrite any changes that you make in IIS Manager by saving an old config file.

Answer (score -2):

In IIS-7 in Windows Server 2008, Windows 7, or Windows Vista SP1, the MIME types supports audio, video, text, HTML and Silver light by default.

Comment: This does not address concern